# Changing the color of a pgfplot within a command dynamically

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to change the color that is used for plotting dynamically while the plot function is embedded in a \newcommand. However I can't get it to show other colors than the last defined one. What do I have to change? I would expect two differently colored lines. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\newcommand\setcolor[1]{\def\mycolor{#1}}
\newcommand\mycolor{black}
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\test}[2]{%
    \addplot[color=#2,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,#1)
        (8,#1)
    };


}

\begin{axis}

    \edef\colora{red}
    \test{1}{\colora}

    \edef\colora{blue}
    \test{2}{\colora}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Current result:
[image: Current result]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you're describing, but this is one way to do it without the `\newcommand`, just using mechanisms provided by `tikz-pgf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \pgfplotstableread{
                x y z
                2 1 2
                8 1 2
            }{\tabledata}
            \addplot[blue] table [x=x, y=y] {\tabledata};
            \addplot[red] table [x=x, y=z] {\tabledata};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This was based on the assumption of two different colors:

> I would expect two differently colored lines.

If you have multiple lines with different colors, then this might not be very efficient. But so is `\newcommand`

If you have multiple data points in every plot, then it might make sense to move the data to a data file and load it as

```
\addplot[red] table [x=x, y=z] {datafile.dat};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm looking for a way to dynamically change colors and then call the function. The plot function is relatively complex and initiates several subplots with multiple colors. Therefore a way to do this nicely would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not overwrite the defined color.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\test}[2]{
    \addplot[color=#2, mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,#1)
        (8,#1)
    };
}
\begin{axis}
    \edef\colora{red}
    \test{1}{\colora}
    \edef\colorb{blue}
    \test{2}{\colorb}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with red and blue line]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! I have a much more complicated plot function whith several nested plots and multiple colors. I am therefore looking for a way where I can define a color palette, call the function, redefine the palette and so on. For example if the color is evaluated at the call of the plot function etc.

Comment: @Dwarfworld: You need to create a new question including a minimal compilable example of what you want.

Comment: I asked specifically for a way where I could overwrite the color definition/ or use a dynamic variable in my question. The added info doesn't change that, it's just to help in understanding why I want it that way. I don't think it's beneficial to post a multi-file document instead of a MWE where I can show the effect I'm talking about. So I don't see how a new question might help. You can look at my answer for a non-elegant way to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: No one asked for a multi-file document. You should always create a MWE. Your answer creates  the same output as mine, but in a less elegant way. Please create a new question with a MWE that illustrates the need you have.

Comment: The original question clearly asks for a dynamic variable, your answer is that I should use a constant. Yes the output is the same, but there would be many ways to create the same output while not answering the question.

Comment: There is no such thing as a dynamically variable. I am telling you that your overwrite you variable and you should not do do it. I can not help you as you are not willing to tell or show what you want and why you want it.

Answer (score 0):

While not really nice I made two axis and superimposed them, which allows me to change the defenition of a color multiple times. If anybody else has a better solution I'll mark that answer as solution.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\test}[2]{%
\addplot[color=#2,mark=x] coordinates {
    (2,#1-1)
    (#1,#1)
};
}

\begin{axis}
\edef\colora{red}
\test{1}{\colora}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
\edef\colora{blue}
\test{2}{\colora}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```